# Were vertical monitor arcade games programmed differently from those with horizontal monitors?

Tags: hardware, crt-monitor, arcade

Many classic arcade games like Pac Man (Namco 1980), Assault (Namco 1988), Mercs (Capcom 1990), etc, use a monitor oriented vertically. I assume that they used the same physical hardware, with the scan lines following the long side of the monitor.

With the monitor rotated, and scan lines going in a different direction, what consequences were there for the game programmer?

Small extra question, were all vertical games' monitors rotated 90° in the same direction, or were some rotated clockwise and others anticlockwise?

Comment: Your question would benefit from copy editing (improved grammar) and clarification about what the problem actually is

Comment: 90° is easy; it's just a really simple co-ordinate transform. (Plot a graph, stick on a point – say, (1, 1), or (2, 5) – and rotate it 90° around (0, 0).) I think this question would be more interesting (and on-topic) if it asked about methods used for _general_ rotations in arcade games.

Comment: Then again… I am actually curious now whether games used separate hardware switches (or logic gates) to remap the lines in some way. _I_ would do it in software, but when every cycle counrs…

Comment: Didn't we already have this?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I guess it may relate to Line Blanking and pseudo-3d thus not limited to simple transformation.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Many arcade machines use tile-mapped backgrounds.  For games with smooth-scrolling backgrounds, having tile boundaries move along scan lines is often harder than having them occur on the same fixed positions every scan line.

Comment: The tabletop arcade games (aka 'cocktail table') flipped depending on on the player, so I suppose they rotated both ways.

Comment: @MarcBernier But cocktail mode change the fundamental: image is not "just" flipped vertically, you rarely are able to store both tiles (up & down). So it's often done with an hardware trick if the video mode and the hardware are correctly designed. A vertical mode is basically a horizontal game. You change all fonts/sprites to be rotated, changes how input are read ("up" means "right", for example), and that's all: you only need to physically rotate the monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Globally, a "vertical" game is a normal "horizontal" game.

Consider the game as if the "up" side of the monitor is the "right" side of the monitor in its normal position (rotated 90° anticlockwise).

You program it really programmed normally, **BUT**:

- All fonts, sprites, etc. are rotated 90° clockwise, so they will be correct with monitor's final position.
- Your scrolling is from right to left, so it will be from up to bottom at the end (like in "1942", for example).
- You still wait normally for HBL/VBL when needed, and framerate isn't modified at all.
- Scanlines are indeed vertical if monitor is simply rotated. If the monitor was built "vertical", then scanlines are horizontal and you simply have a strange video mode.
- The tricky part is joystick: when you read (resp.) "up/left/down/right" on the joystick, you must interpret it as (resp.) "right/up/left/down", so movements are consistent with the final monitor position. Please note that you can also rewire direction inputs on the PCB internally, so you can still use the standard JAMMA connector and pinout, but internally, you decide to wire the JAMMA "up" as a "right". It may allows to use the exact same hardware (and even some code ROMs) for both horizontal and vertical games with only some jumpers onboard to set the mode.

So things aren't so different for the programmer, but for direction inputs if problem isn't solved directly through hardware.
It was a bit more different for the graphic designer, first because of the rotation, and second because the aspect ratio *MAY* have an influence on design with some video modes, because not only are the pixels still not square, but they are also oriented in the opposite direction as usual.

Comment: confirmed with scramble disassembly. X and Y are swapped all right. Oh and it's even more complex with cocktail mode when the screens are inverted to face the player on the cocktail table.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Cocktail is another thing. For example, if your vertical resolution is a power of two (ex: 256 pixels), you can set up a hardware circuit that will swap the address lines from/to video chip, so that when you emit the line 0, it emits the line 255, line 1 becomes line 254, and so on. So, image is flipped vertically without needing to have all tiles in two directions, or to do a software trick that CAN made one mode slower than the other.

Comment: this is probably what happens, you're right. Else it would take twice as much the memory just for a possible cocktail mode

Comment: Cocktail operation is interesting; from what I can tell, many games had hardware to flip some aspects of the display, but not necessarily everything.  As a consequence, if glitches result in the screen being inverted in hardware without software knowing about it, or vice versa, that may result in e.g. objects whose shapes are upside down, being shown on an inverted background, but moving the same way as they would if the screen were upright.

Comment: @supercat Another thing is that cocktail mode is often something that isn't properly emulated with a LOT of games, so it's clearly not a matter of a pure software operation (otherwise, it would work already since the ROMs, and then the software, is already dumped). It's clearly a missing hardware device that has an effect _only_ when the 2nd player is active in Cocktail mode... When setting the dip switches to standard mode, 2nd player can play normally. The hardware flip could also be done only on tiles/graphic ROM, not on the video circuit itself.

Comment: @Wisblade: On many machines, it's easier to have a global switch to invert all tiles and the pixel patterns of all shapes, than it is to give software the ability to individually flip tiles and sprites, but software would always *inherently* have the ability to flip the coordinates used to position sprites.  There's thus no need to have hardware do that.  If one had a game in which all sprites and tiles would need to be displayable in any orientation, there would be no need to have a hardware "cocktail mode", but if a game doesn't need such flexibility hardware to provide it would be wasteful.

Comment: @supercat Cocktail mode was often only a dip switch on the board, and not a specific board that supported cocktail mode. If it were totally software (i.e. read the dip switch position and execute code accordingly), then **ALL** games supporting cocktail mode would be emulated perfectly in this mode. This isn't the case, so it implies that there is missing emulated hardware - since all program is properly dumped _and_ dip switches are properly read within emulator. Flipping tiles on-the-fly (they aren't in RAM, but in ROM) would have let player 2 use more CPU in cocktail mode, and it wasn't.